# regex matching dp

Tags: regex, algorithm

I was trying to understand one of the famous regex matching DP algorithm.
Just in case, people don't know this here is description and algorithm.

```
'.' Matches any single character.
'*' Matches zero or more of the preceding element.

The matching should cover the entire input string (not partial).

The function prototype should be:
bool isMatch(const char *s, const char *p)
```

---

```
Some examples:
isMatch("aa","a") → false
isMatch("aa","aa") → true
isMatch("aaa","aa") → false
isMatch("aa", "a*") → true
isMatch("aa", ".*") → true
isMatch("ab", ".*") → true
isMatch("aab", "c*a*b") → true


static boolean isMatch(String s, String p) {
    boolean[][] dp = new boolean[s.length() + 1][p.length() + 1];
    dp[0][0] = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < dp[0].length; i++) {
        if (p.charAt(i - 1) == '*') {
            dp[0][i] = dp[0][i - 2];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < dp.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < dp[0].length; j++) {
            char schar = s.charAt(i - 1);
            char pchar = p.charAt(j - 1);
            if (schar == pchar || pchar == '.') {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1];
            } else if (pchar == '*') {
                if (schar != p.charAt(j - 2) && p.charAt(j - 2) != '.') {
                    //   - a b *
                    // - t f f f
                    // a f t f t // b != a and b != '.' thus treat b* as 0 match
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 2];
                } else {
                    //   - a b *
                    // - t f f f
                    // a f t f t
                    // b f f t t // dp[i][j - 2] 0 match or dp[i][j - 1] 1 math or dp[i - 1][j] 2+ match (not sure why)
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 2] || dp[i][j - 1] || dp[i - 1][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[s.length()][p.length()];
}
```

I understand the most of part but this part I don't get it

```
dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 2] || dp[i][j - 1] || dp[i - 1][j];
```

`dp[i - 1][j]` people said this will cover 2+ matches but don't understand this part. Can someone please explain why I need to check `dp[i - 1][j]`?

Comment: `isMatch("aab", "c*a*b") → true` -- why is it true?

Comment: @Serge because '*' Matches zero or more of the preceding element. So take 'c' 0 times !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assumption here that the string will not contain special characters **' . '** and  **' * '** because otherwise the code presented won't work !!*

**What does `dp[i][j]` represents?**

It represents that if only first **i** characters of string and **j** characters of pattern are considered, do they match ?

**State transition in case we encounter '*' in pattern:**

**Case 1:** Take only 0 number of character preceding **' * '**  in pattern.

The **' * '** alone doesn't mean anything. It is dependent on its preceding character.

`dp[i][j-2]` will completely ignore the preceding character in pattern as it considers only first **j-2** characters, so preceding character along with **' * '** (**jth** character) in pattern are ignored.

---

***Now if it is a case that the **ith** character in string and character preceding **' * '** happen to be same or character preceding **' * '** in pattern is **' . '** then 1 more case add up.***

**Observation here**:  **.*** can match any string

---

**If above condition is satisfied, then consider below case.**

**Case 2:** Continuation of usage of character preceding  **' * '** for one or more times.

`dp[i-1][j]` represents this. Remember **jth** character in pattern is **' * '** .

So if first **i-1** characters of string match with first **j** characters in pattern where **jth** character is a **' * '** (which suggests that we have used character preceding **' * '** at least once), then we can say that first **i** characters in string match with first **j** characters of pattern as we have already ensured that **ith** character matches the preceding character to **' * '** in pattern.

The case `dp[i][j-1]` is redundant and covered in case 2.

**Note: Explanation for redundancy of `dp[i][j-1]`**

`dp[i][j-1]` matches only once for character preceding **' * '**. It is already covered in `dp[i-1][j]`.

Reason:

We know **ith** character is matching **j-1th** character (Remember, we checked before considering this case).

So `dp[i][j-1]` = `dp[i-1][j-2]` which is already considered in calculation of `dp[i-1][j]`.

`dp[i-1][j]` is more powerful because `dp[i-1][j] = dp[i-1][j-2] || dp[i-2][j]` as jth character is **' * '**. So this is what gives memory property which allows us to use a character more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a bit more informal notation so bear with me.
Capitals will denote strings (in the pattern those could include the special characters) and lowercase letters, '.' and '*' will stand for themselves.

Let's say we're matching Ax to Bx, that is some string starting with A (which is itself a string, like xyzz) ending in 'x', with a pattern starting with B (which is itself a pattern, for example, x.*) ending in 'x'. The result is the same as that of matching A to B (as we have no other choice but to match x to x).

We could write that as follows:

```
isMatch(Ax, Bx) = isMatch(A, B)
```

Similarly, matching Ax to By is impossible.

```
isMatch(Ax, Bx) = false
```

Easy enough. So that would correspond to the first if statement in the two nested loops.

Now let's take the case of an asterisk.
Matching Ax to By* can only be done by ignoring the y* (taking zero y's), that is by matching Ax to B.

```
isMatch(Ax, By*) = isMatch(Ax, B)
```

If however the y is replaced by a dot or by x, there are choices.
We'll take the case of Ax and Bx*. The two options are matching Ax to B (means taking zero x's) or matching A to Bx* (means taking an x, but we can still take more so the pattern doesn't change):

```
isMatch(Ax, Bx*) = isMatch(Ax, B) || isMatch(A, Bx*)
```

The last one would, in your code, translate to:

```
dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 2] || dp[i - 1][j]
```

So now I'm wondering if your question was really about `dp[i][j - 1]`, as that's what would confuse me.

I might be wrong but that one seems unnecessary.

The meaning of it is to drop the asterisk, that is, changing "zero or more"
to "exactly one", which is already covered by the other two cases, taking the second followed by the first.

Comment: I agree with you. `dp[i][j-1]` is redundant.